# Foursquare venues/search doesn't return full categories list

Tags: api, foursquare

For example in this request I'm looking for venues with categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e8941735 (Baseball Field): https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D40.7,-74%26categoryId%3D4bf58dd8d48988d1e8941735

In the result each venue has only one (primary) category. Is it possible in venuess/search request to return full venue's categories list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

This is actually by design, for performance considerations. In contexts where we return many JSON items (e.g. venues/search), we only provide the "compact" JSON to keep overall response-size down, since it's a significant contributor to the cost of serving and handling the request. venues/search in particular is one of our most highly trafficked endpoints.

If you want more detail about a particular result in venues/search, you should query the venue-detail endpoint (/venues/[VENUE-ID]), which will return the full list of categories.